# How to store images used in a Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, image, mobile, file-upload

I am wanting to develop a mobile app for the travel industry - a Travel Diary.  Ideally, users could use this app when offline - like when they are on a plane or they do not have access to the the internet (maybe hiking in the bush).

As part of the travel diary, users can 'attach' a picture from their device.  As the images are stored on the user's device, how can I prevent those images from being deleted if the user deletes the App?

I am thinking that the app doesnt store the image but rather a link to the image.  Can this even be done?  How would it be done?  I would want the user to be able to attach an image to a given/specified day.  eg I went to the Eiffel Tower on Saturday 15 July 23.

The data storage would also apply to other data entered into the app such as the actual diary note (I did this and that today and it was great...etc).  If this data is deleted if the app is deleted, then thats OK.

Users would be comfortable that their data is stored on their device IMO, plus its saves me having to arrange storage for what could be terabytes of data storing images.  I'm no Facebook or Instagram.

Any advice would be most welcomed.

Comment: use any SQL(sqflite) or non-SQL (get Storage, Hive, ObjectBox) database to store images in a phone and retrieve them whenever based on your need

Comment: Many thanks.  So during signup process, have the App instal the database onto the users device?

Comment: basically, yes.